# Encryption and Decyption using RSA and Certificates in C# throws

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, x509certificate2

I am trying to encrypt a secret (string) with a certificate. This is needed to encrypt a password in a text file. Then this has to be decrypted every time the password is needed but that decryption is failing and throwing:

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'The parameter is incorrect.

Any idea what is wrong? This is used to create the encrypted string to include in config file

```
byte[] secretEncrypted = null;
using (RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey())
{
    secretEncrypted = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(secret), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
}
string secretEncryptedstr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(secretEncrypted);
```

I hope I could use this to decrypt the string from a config file but this is failing

```
byte[] secretDecrypted;
using (RSA rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    secretDecrypted = rsa.Decrypt(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(secretEncryptedstr), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA512);
}
string secretDecryptedstr = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(secretDecrypted);
```

Certificate is the same in both code segments.

Comment: Passwords cannot be decrypted they are only one way.  To compare passwords you have to encrypt and then compare the encrypted value.

Comment: Ah, another encoding error. RSA returns a (mostly) random byte string and not all bytes represent UTF16LE (what the badly named `Unicode` class represents), which results in mangled ciphertext. Use base 64 if you require text for your encrypted password.